# How to create a list of lists in scheme?

Tags: scheme, nested-lists, chicken-scheme

I may have missed this in the R5RS document but how do I create a list of lists in (Chicken) Scheme? I want to be able to take a list, `a`, invoke `(list-ref a b)`, assign the result to `c`, and then invoke `(list-ref c d)`, where `b` and `d` are index values.

Edit: For clarification, suppose I have these lists:

```
(define citrus (list "oranges" "limes"))
(define apples (list "macintosh" "rome" "delicious"))
```

And then I want to create a list called `fruit` with the `citrus` and `apples` as list entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a list containing those lists, just call `list` with them as arguments:

```
(define fruit (list citrus apples))

(list-ref (list-ref fruit 0) 1)
=> "lime"
```

Comment: The code is wrong, the given indexes return `"limes"`, not `"rome"`

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you create a list of lists:

```
(list (list 1 2) (list 3 4))
```

Or even simpler:

```
'((1 2) (3 4))
```

Now, if you already have the other sublists defined as separate lists, put them inside an outer list calling `list` again on them:

```
(define the-first  (list 1 2))
(define the-second (list 3 4))
(define list-of-lists (list the-first the-second))
list-of-lists
=> '((1 2) (3 4))
```

To access a position given two indexes, do this - remember, indexes are zero-based:

```
(define lst '((1 2) (3 4)))
(list-ref (list-ref lst 1) 0)
=> 3
```

So, the first example in the question would look like this:

```
(define a '((1 2) (3 4)))
(define b 1)
(define c (list-ref a b))
(define d 0)
(list-ref c d)
=> 3
```

And the second example (after the edit) would look like this:

```
(define citrus (list "oranges" "limes"))
(define apples (list "macintosh" "rome" "delicious"))
(define fruit (list citrus apples)) ; here's the list of lists
```

Now, to access an element first we have to pass the index of the outermost list (let's say we want apples, which are at index `1` in the outermost list) and then the index of the innermost list (let's say we want a macintosh, which is at index `0` in the apples sublist):

```
(list-ref (list-ref fruit 1) 0)
=> "macintosh"
```